# VisualStudio won't accept credentials in enterprise environment - StatusCode: 0x80090308

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, visual-studio, team-foundation-server, ntlm

I'm currently using Visual Studio Community 2015, Version 14.0 Update 3.

My problem is, that I can't connect to my own MS TeamFoundationServer 2015 from my workplace. The problem is definitely not missing access rights, because I can connect from anywhere except my office.

I try to add my TFS using TeamExplorer -> Connect to team project -> Servers -> Add. Then I enter my connection data (which is correct, double- and triple-checked). After that, I'm asked for my credentials as seen in this picture (URL and Username changed for the pic):

[image]

But even if I enter the correct credentials, it won't let me connect. It displays the following error:

[image]

For me, this looks like my credentials are wrong. Except they aren't. I just double checked this on a few other PCs.

The cause of the problem is probably the authentication of my company. Because if I try to open the TFS-Page in the VisualStudio browser (`Ctrl + W` and then `W`), I instantly get the following error, an usual IIS 401.

[image]

But usually I get asked for my credentials if I try to open this page, on every browser. Except on the VS-Browser.

So does VisualStudio tries to authenticate me automatically with my Windows-Credentials? If so, where can I turn this off? If not, what could be the problem?

I don't think it's because of a firewall or a proxy, because I can connect to the TFS, but just not authenticate.

**EDIT** for further information.

First, I am the administrator of the TFS myself.

I created the user "TfsUser" on my Server, so his full name is "WINDOWSSERVER\TfsUser". If I log in with this username (and his password), I get in without problem if I'm anywhere except my office. If I enter the credentials correctly, the Windows Security window keeps popping up (like if you misspelled your password). After about three to four (but can also be two or five) tries, the Error from Image 2 pops up.

**Edit 2**

I dived deeper into the issue. On my server, I saw the following entry in my security event log:

Logon Failure:

- Reason: An error occurred during logon
- Security ID: NULL SID
- User Name: TfsUser
- Domain: WINDOWSSERVER
- Authentication Package: NTLM
- Workstation Name:
- **Status code: 0x80090308**
- Substatus code: 0x0

With this status code, I find the following SU-Question (with no answer and no information to help me): [AD DC - Error 4625 Status 0x80090308](https://serverfault.com/questions/702594/ad-dc-error-4625-status-0x80090308)

Comment: Have your administrator correct the TF configuration

Comment: I am the administrator. And I have done everything, my TFS is accessible but just not from within the company net. What should I correct in the TF configuration @Ramhound?

Comment: "Use another account";  you have not indicated how your normally authenticate to the TF.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not entirely sure what you mean... I just changed the Name for the picture, not for the authentication. I use the same Username / Domain from everywhere, just from my office it doesn't works. Or what do you mean by "Use another account"?

Comment: So you use your Windows account to access authenticate your TF account?  "But usually I get asked for my credentials if I try to open this page, on every browser." - This indicates to me you are not doing that

Comment: I made an user on the Server, which I enabled for TFS. Let's say his name is "TfsUser". On my Computer, the User is usually for example "John". So if I want to add the Server to VS, I get asked for credentials and I enter "WINDOWSSERVER\TfsUser" with his password and get in with no problem. Except if I do the same from my workplace (go to VS -> Add Server and try to log in). I get the window asking me for the credentials (image 1), but if I enter them correctly, it keeps telling me that I'm not allowed to access TFS. BTW: Thanks for helping! :) @Ramhound

Comment: ....`WindowsServer\TFSUSER\` indicates a Active Domain user namd TFSUSER on the WindowsServer domain.  If you created a TFS user that would be the wrong way to identify that.

Comment: I created the User "TFSUSER" on the Domain "WindowsServer". I can log in via RDP (for example). Then I went to the TFS, to my Collection and under "permissions" added this User. I can connect from everywhere, so authentication or userbase shouldn't be the problem. There's just one location I can't log in: In my office.

Comment: Is there something special about DNS in your office?

Comment: Check out internet authentication settings. https://support.software.dell.com/KBArticleImages/118560/SecuritySettings.jpg

Comment: @harrymc no, not as far as I can tell. Are there any ways I can find this out?

@ssnobody it's set to `Automatic logon only in Intranet zone`. I think, this is the desired behaviour, isn't it?

Comment: I would think you want to "prompt for username and password." In particular, doesn't this answer your question of "So does VisualStudio tries to authenticate me automatically with my Windows-Credentials? If so, where can I turn this off?"

Comment: Well, not necessarily. I am getting prompted for username and password in VisualStudio. It just keeps me telling, that my credentials are "incorrect", although they are correct... But I will give it a try.

Comment: please have a look at MSDN for TF31003 http://bit.ly/2aYYF7J

Comment: @mussdroid thanks for the link. Sadly, none of the options did work for me. I think, it must be the company-firewall which blocks the authentication-requests.